# How to escape quote and apostrophe within a JS call within a tag within a JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP which gets an arbitrary string, stored in a backend object; call it ${state.status.code}.

I want to pass this string to a function when a table element is clicked; I'm using onClick to invoke my JS function `showStatus`. Put together it looks like this:

```
<c:set var="statusString" value="${state.status.code}" />
<td id="${rowId}"><a href="#" 
                   class="pClass" 
                   onClick="showStatus('${statusString}')>
                   Here be status
                  </a>
```

The problem is that statusString may have double quotes or apostrophes in it, and I can't figure out how to escape them. I have been trying various things in the `c:set` tag: `fn:replace` with ' and ", `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(statusString)`, and fn:escapeXml(statusString). It is possible one of those works, but that I have put it in the wrong place, delimited by the wrong characters, or just haven't held my mouth right.

I can always substitute them for some arbitrary unique string ("!#$#!") and then replace them when I get to displaying the HTML popup within showStatus, but that seems really ugly for such a simple-seeming problem. Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and pass the parameter to your javascript function this way

```
onclick="showStatus('<c:out value="${esapi:encodeForJavaScript(statusString)}" />')"
```

and in order to use esapi tag, you have to include the following in your jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API"prefix="esapi" %>
```

and if the jar is missing the
esapi.tld in the META-INF dir, please read in the following link the first answer:
https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/issues/detail?id=237

as there are the steps to do in order to make it work.